# Smarty sort array with usort

Tags: arrays, sorting, smarty, usort

I am creating an array within a template using:

```
{foreach from=$items item=node} 
{if $node->fielddefs.location01.value != ''}{$locations[] = $node->fielddefs.location01.value}{/if} 
{if $node->fielddefs.location02.value != ''}{$locations[] = $node->fielddefs.location02.value}{/if} 
{if $node->fielddefs.location02.value != ''}{$locations[] = $node->fielddefs.location03.value}{/if} 
{/foreach}
```

I need to sort the array alphabetically. I have tried the following usort function:

```
if (!function_exists('do_sort')) { 
    function do_sort($a, $b) { 
        return $a > $b; 
    } 
} 
$data = $params['data']; 
usort($data, 'do_sort'); 
$smarty->assign('sorted', $data);
```

It does now work because my array is not correct I guess? My array looks like this:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Any 
    [1] => Chamonix 
    [2] => Courmayeur 
    [3] => Verbier 
    [4] => Zermatt 
    [5] => Verbier 
    [6] => Chamonix 
)
```

Can anyone help me achieve a sorted output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function do_sort($a, $b) { 
    return $a < $b ? -1 : 1; 
}
```

The callback in the `usort` function should return -1, 0, or 1 (or, more generally, a positive number, a negative number or zero), not true/false.